# Java Android Api

Tags: java, json, api, pojo

Есть API криптобиржи Yobit "https://yobit.net/api/3/info"
Не могу понять именно момент "pairs":{"ltc_btc":{"..."}}
на месте "ltc_btc" каждый раз новая валютная пара
jsonschema2pojo предлагает для каждой валютной пары создавать отдельный POJO, а их там OVER много. Как это описать подтолкните пожалуйста

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант для не ленивых**

1. Копируете содержимое json
2. Идете на ресурсы, позволяющие груду json текста представить в удобочитаемом варианте. Например, [тут](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)
3. Видим структуру json, и пытаемся основываясь на том, что видим, собрать pojo

**Вариант для ленивых**

1. Берем пункт №1 из варианта для ленивых
2. Опять же, идете на ресурсы, позволяющие груду json текста представить не только в удобочитаемом варианте, но и еще собрать за вас pojo на удобном ЯП, например, [здесь](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2java)
3. Вставляем json вывод и получаем готовый класс

Ваш класс из варианта для ленивых:

```
public class Lazy {
    private long serverTime;
    private Map<String, Pair> pairs;

    @JsonProperty("server_time")
    public long getServerTime() { return serverTime; }
    @JsonProperty("server_time")
    public void setServerTime(long value) { this.serverTime = value; }

    @JsonProperty("pairs")
    public Map<String, Pair> getPairs() { return pairs; }
    @JsonProperty("pairs")
    public void setPairs(Map<String, Pair> value) { this.pairs = value; }
}

// Pair.java

import java.util.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class Pair {
    private long decimalPlaces;
    private double minPrice;
    private long maxPrice;
    private double minAmount;
    private double minTotal;
    private long hidden;
    private double fee;
    private double feeBuyer;
    private double feeSeller;

    @JsonProperty("decimal_places")
    public long getDecimalPlaces() { return decimalPlaces; }
    @JsonProperty("decimal_places")
    public void setDecimalPlaces(long value) { this.decimalPlaces = value; }

    @JsonProperty("min_price")
    public double getMinPrice() { return minPrice; }
    @JsonProperty("min_price")
    public void setMinPrice(double value) { this.minPrice = value; }

    @JsonProperty("max_price")
    public long getMaxPrice() { return maxPrice; }
    @JsonProperty("max_price")
    public void setMaxPrice(long value) { this.maxPrice = value; }

    @JsonProperty("min_amount")
    public double getMinAmount() { return minAmount; }
    @JsonProperty("min_amount")
    public void setMinAmount(double value) { this.minAmount = value; }

    @JsonProperty("min_total")
    public double getMinTotal() { return minTotal; }
    @JsonProperty("min_total")
    public void setMinTotal(double value) { this.minTotal = value; }

    @JsonProperty("hidden")
    public long getHidden() { return hidden; }
    @JsonProperty("hidden")
    public void setHidden(long value) { this.hidden = value; }

    @JsonProperty("fee")
    public double getFee() { return fee; }
    @JsonProperty("fee")
    public void setFee(double value) { this.fee = value; }

    @JsonProperty("fee_buyer")
    public double getFeeBuyer() { return feeBuyer; }
    @JsonProperty("fee_buyer")
    public void setFeeBuyer(double value) { this.feeBuyer = value; }

    @JsonProperty("fee_seller")
    public double getFeeSeller() { return feeSeller; }
    @JsonProperty("fee_seller")
    public void setFeeSeller(double value) { this.feeSeller = value; }
}
```